# How to compare each value of row in a dataframe with each value in the row before with python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, compare

I have a dataframe, which looks something like this (number of columns and rows can differ):

```
                0         1         2
2015-01-02    ISIN1     ISIN2     ISIN3
2015-05-04    ISIN4     ISIN2     ISIN5
2015-09-01    ISIN4     ISIN5     ISIN6
2016-01-04    ISIN7     ISIN8     ISIN2
2016-05-02    ISIN9     ISIN7     ISIN10
2016-09-01    ISIN11    ISIN12    ISIN13
2017-01-02    ISIN11    ISIN12    ISIN14
2017-05-02    ISIN12    ISIN11    ISIN15
2017-09-01    ISIN12    ISIN16    ISIN17
2018-01-02    ISIN16    ISIN11    ISIN18
2018-05-02    ISIN4     ISIN8     ISIN7
2018-09-03    ISIN12    ISIN7     ISIN19
2019-01-02    ISIN20    ISIN21    ISIN22
2019-05-02    ISIN13    ISIN7     ISIN8
2019-09-02    ISIN23    ISIN24    ISIN15
2020-01-02    ISIN25    ISIN23    ISIN24
2020-05-04    ISIN24    ISIN26    ISIN4
```

My task is now to compare each value of each row with each value of the row before. I want to know if the value is in the row before or not. I want to get two dataframes as result.

1. Keep the values which are not in the row before:

   ```
                   0         1         2
   2015-01-02    ISIN1     ISIN2     ISIN3
   2015-05-04    ISIN4     ISIN5
   2015-09-01    ISIN6
   2016-01-04    ISIN7     ISIN8     ISIN2
   2016-05-02    ISIN9     ISIN10
   2016-09-01    ISIN11    ISIN12    ISIN13
   2017-01-02    ISIN14
   2017-05-02    ISIN15
   2017-09-01    ISIN16    ISIN17
   2018-01-02    ISIN11    ISIN18
   2018-05-02    ISIN4     ISIN8     ISIN7
   2018-09-03    ISIN12    ISIN19
   2019-01-02    ISIN20    ISIN21    ISIN22
   2019-05-02    ISIN13    ISIN7     ISIN8
   2019-09-02    ISIN23    ISIN24    ISIN15
   2020-01-02    ISIN25    
   2020-05-04    ISIN26    ISIN4
   ```
2. Keep the values which are in the row before:

   ```
                   0         1         2
   2015-01-02    
   2015-05-04    ISIN2
   2015-09-01    ISIN4     ISIN5
   2016-01-04    
   2016-05-02    ISIN7
   2016-09-01    
   2017-01-02    ISIN11    ISIN12    
   2017-05-02    ISIN12    ISIN11    
   2017-09-01    ISIN12    
   2018-01-02    ISIN16    
   2018-05-02    
   2018-09-03    ISIN7
   2019-01-02    
   2019-05-02    
   2019-09-02    
   2020-01-02    ISIN23    ISIN24
   2020-05-04    ISIN24
   ```

What I've explored so far:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    print(np.isin(df.values[i, :], df.shift().values[i, :]))
```

creates this:

```
[False False False]
[False  True False]
[ True  True False]
[False False False]
[False  True False]
[False False False]
[ True  True False]
[ True  True False]
[ True False False]
[ True False False]
[False False False]
[False  True False]
[False False False]
[False False False]
[False False False]
[False  True  True]
[ True False False]
```

With appending this values to a list I would be able to create a new dataframe. But I think there must be a better way.

Does anyone have a clue how to do it without iterating through the dataframe?

Thank you very much!

Best regards,
nepy

Comment: I don't know if it's possible without the iteration because you would need to be constantly appending the values to a list whenever a new row is read. That's to my knowledge, surely someone will help you out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I digged a deep further. My solution is now:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

row_0 = np.array(['ISIN1', 'ISIN4', 'ISIN4', 'ISIN7', 'ISIN9', 'ISIN11', 'ISIN11', 'ISIN12', 'ISIN12', 'ISIN16', 'ISIN4', 'ISIN12', 'ISIN20', 'ISIN13', 'ISIN23', 'ISIN25', 'ISIN24'])
row_1 = np.array(['ISIN2', 'ISIN2', 'ISIN5', 'ISIN8', 'ISIN7', 'ISIN12', 'ISIN12', 'ISIN11', 'ISIN16', 'ISIN11', 'ISIN8', 'ISIN7', 'ISIN21', 'ISIN7', 'ISIN24', 'ISIN23', 'ISIN26'])
row_2 = np.array(['ISIN3', 'ISIN5', 'ISIN6', 'ISIN2', 'ISIN10', 'ISIN13', 'ISIN14', 'ISIN15', 'ISIN17', 'ISIN18', 'ISIN7', 'ISIN19', 'ISIN22', 'ISIN8', 'ISIN15', 'ISIN24', 'ISIN4'])

data = {0:row_0, 1:row_1, 2:row_2}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
df_in_row_before = df[pd.DataFrame(np.array([np.isin(df.values[i, :], df.shift().values[i, :]) for i in range(len(df))]))]

print(df_in_row_before)
df_not_in_row_before = df[pd.DataFrame(np.array([np.isin(df.values[i, :], df.shift().values[i, :], invert=True) for i in range(len(df))]))]
print(df_not_in_row_before)
```

This makes exactly what i needed. But if anyone have a better solution I'm happy to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to replace duplicate values by NaN:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1,1,2,2,4], b=[0,5,6,6,8]), index=np.arange(5)+100)
mask = np.full_like(df, False, dtype=bool)
mask[1:] =  df.iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True) == df.iloc[:-1].reset_index(drop=True)
df[mask] = None
```

The `reset_index` operations are needed because otherwise, pandas will attempt to do the `==` comparison on matching row indices.

Original DataFrame:

```
     a  b
100  1  0
101  1  5
102  2  6
103  2  6
104  4  8
```

After:

```
       a    b
100  1.0  0.0
101  NaN  5.0
102  2.0  6.0
103  NaN  NaN
104  4.0  8.0
```

For the reverse, you need to do

```
mask = np.logical_not(mask)
```

Comment: Hello Han-Kwang Nienhuys, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately your solution does not search in all columns. Only the same column is compared with the row before. So in case for example ISIN5 on 2015-09-01 in column '1' it shows ISIN5. But because on 2015-05-04 ISIN5 is in column '2' there should be a 'None' on 2015-09-01 in column '1'.

Answer (score 0):

Hey maybe You are looking for something like:

```
data = {'first': ['ok', 'none', 'ok', 'ok', 'ok', 'ok', 'ok', 'ok', 'none', 'ok'],
        'second': [1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 2, 4, 9, 6, 9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['first', 'second'])

df_results = df.eq(df.shift())
df_results.where(df_results != False, df)
```

Hope it help

Comment: This doesn't delete duplicate values, but replaces them by True.

Comment: Yes I know but, deleting True values is not a big deal, so I do not add this in code above. You can add another line like:

df_results.where(df_results!= True , np.nan)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately df.eq() only compares the same columns. So in case for example ISIN5 on 2015-09-01 in column '1' it generates a 'False'. But on 2015-05-04 ISIN5 is in column '2'.